# Heroku: custom domain

Tags: heroku, subdomain

Trying to host a custom domain with Heroku. i have putting the following into terminal -

```
CNAME www.example.com example.herokuap.com
```

but I keeping getting the following error

```
 -bash: CNAME: command not found
```

**help**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a Heroku command, you need to use the Heroku CLI

```
heroku domains:add www.example.com
```

or do it from the web dashboard.

You then need to setup a CNAME record with your DNS provider to set www.example.com to example.herokuapp.com

Comment: Are there any free DNS providers and what exactly is the CNAME used for? Is it needed?

Comment: typically who ever you've registered your domain name with will have some kind of DNS control panel. The purpose of your CNAME is to make your website accessible on your choosen domain name.

Comment: This is the correct answer. This tells the Heroku DNS servers to resolve the CNAME and point it to your app.